# NGINX reverse proxy in front of docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, internal-dns

How do we get NGINX reverse proxy to `proxy_pass` into the right IP/resolve the container's hostname?  I get the notion that `resolver` pointing to an exposed Docker-embedded DNS is ideal.

Context: Debian Host (not dockerized) NGINX.  Docker containers are on same host and necessarily on an `overlay` network and working well in their own right.

I've been experimenting & reading for hours on this and similar posts include:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729663/query-docker-embedded-dns-from-host

I was unable to get `nslookup` to work with Consul and various DNSmasq stuff

`socat` approach nearly got me there, but it resolves and spits out the non-exposed (non-overlay) network IP

Comment: Have a look at [jwilder automatic nginx proxy for docker](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). There now other products offering the same kind of service (and much more... like [traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik)), but jwilder implementation is simple and easy to study to understand how things are done.

Comment: Quite interesting -- especially the `docker-gen` part!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?
As far as I know, when running a docker container you should open its ports on the docker host. This way the nginx proxy configuration can point to the desired port on the local address (localhost/127.0.0.1).

For example I would run:
`docker run -p 8080:8080 myapp`

Then configure Nginx with:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    ... other desired options ...
}
```

Comment: My use case originally was containers were floating on a network, possibly DHCP'd, with nginx proxy elsewhere